# Manjaro: First seconds of "new" sound source missing

Tags: audio, arch-linux, manjaro

I switched from Ubuntu to Manjaro and I encountered this weird behavior where the first 1-3 seconds of most sound sources are missing.

This mostly happens in Browsers,  e.g with Youtube. Tested it witch both Chrome and Firefox.

Edit: Also happens when I pause the video for just a second.

Any idea why this happens and how I can fix this?

I use Manjaro 19.04 KDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your audio hardware (codec) probably has [power saving](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.0/sound/designs/powersave.html) enabled – the kernel powers it off after no program is using it anymore, and it takes a while for the hardware to properly turn on once it's needed again (sometimes intentionally, so that loud power-on pops could be avoided).

To temporarily lengthen the powersave timeout or even completely disable this feature, run (assuming the system is using Intel HDA, which many do):

```
echo 0 > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save
```

Permanently:

1. Add `options snd_hda_intel power_save=0` to /etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf
2. Rebuild the initramfs and reboot

The number indicates how many seconds the device can remain idle, but `0` disables power-off.